# Syntax for iterating through a C array

Tags: c

I'm a beginner learning C. I'm quite familiar with Java, where iterating through an array i is as simple as:

```
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
// Stuff here
```

But in C, the * notation throws me off. Can someone please explain why the input variable below refers to an array, and the syntax for iterating through it?

```
double function(const double* values);
```

Comment: Generally, you cannot iterate over such pointers as you don't actually know what kind of data they point to

Comment: you have a typo, after ```i = 0``` there is ```;``` , not ```:```

Comment: @ForceBru in the example `values` points to `double` type data. More to the point, you cannot know the extent of any iteration without also knowing the number of elements.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Either you missed the prerequisites (pointers) for any short enough answer or it results in further questions. Please understand we are not a tutoring site, to learn C, you should consult a good C book.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't refer to an array, it refers to a single `const double` element. However, that element could very well be the first in an array of constant doubles.

So if we preform pointer arithmetic, we may reference other elements in the array. To do that, you can use the subscript operator `values[i]`. But you must ensure that you only compute and reference addresses that are in the array. And you cannot know that from the pointer value alone.

So unless your function is modified to receive a size parameter as well, you may not generally reference any element besides the one whose address was passed.

Once you have the size available to you, however, iteration should look just as you'd expect it from your Java experience:

```
double function(const size_t num_elem, const double* values) {
  double result = 0.0;
  // .. pre iteration stuff
  for (size_t i = 0; i < num_elem; ++i) {
    if (values[i] < 1e-6)
      // do something
  }
  // post iteration stuff
  return result;
}
```

Comment: It's worth noting that, with the caveats you've specified, iterating over an array in C can be done more or less via the same method the OP described for Java.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Yes, I was just cooking up some semi-sample code.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays in C are a chunk of memory allocated to hold a number of elements of a certain type. The way you access each element is by using a pointer to the memory location and dereferencing it (i.e. `*ptr`).

`values` is a pointer to a memory location where a `double` can be stored. Assuming it points to the first location of a chunk of memory allocated to store `double`s you can access the first element in that chunk by either doing `*values` or `values[0]`. The second element would be accessed with `*(values + 1)` or `values[1]`. And so on.

Given this, you can't know how big the chunk of memory is by just having the location to the start. The function needs to take another argument that tells it how many elements are supposed to be there.

```
double function(const double* values, const int count);
```

If you are just starting with C I suggest you dig a little bit deeper into the fundamentals of the language. I have found [The C Programming Language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language)
 extremely simple, short and informative when it comes to grasping the fundamentals of C.

Answer (score 0):

Pure C arrays don't know their sizes (which is why C is quite powerful). You can index anything at any point (as long as the OS allows you to)

so,

```
int main ( )
{
    //size of your array, you could use size_t which is type for sizes I'll not be doing so,
    //to simplify the code
    const int size = 10


    //both "size", the type and the name of the array are virtually infinitely flexible
    int array[size] = {0}//never forget to initialize your array, or you'll get garbage.

    //in pure C, you have to declare i before using it, here I declare and also initialize it
    //because, why not?
    int i = 0;

    //since i have already been initialized, I could easily rewrite the for statement below:
    //for ( ; i < size; ++i ) no initialization required. 
    for ( i = 0; i < size; ++ i )
    {
        array[i] //do whatever you want.
    }
}
```